# Inter node DC delay in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

Cassandra Inter Node DC delay calculation. How determine the level of delay.

We enabled two DC's: DC1 and DC2. Every thing seems to be running fine. How do we identify the time delay between the DC's. We are using Local_Quorum. How to determine if there is delay in DC2 if DC1 is already committed. We are using local_quorum for both reads and writes.

To what extend we can see changes when the inter_dc_tcp_nodelay is enabled vs disabled. I looking for queries and number to identify in my environment.

Thanks 
Tom

Answer (score 2):

In Cassandra there is a JMX metric that measures latency to the specific data center: `org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Messaging,name={dc}-Latency` (replace `{dc}` with the name of the data center.

There are also some tools for checking how fast data is replicated:

- https://github.com/QuentinAmbard/dse-replication-lag
- https://github.com/gitaroktato/cassandra-replication-latency-tools